# Using OkHttp with existing HttpUrlConnection code?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I've just started working on an (existing) Android project that uses HttpUrlConnection to communicate with a RESTful web service.  Today I realized that one of the REST calls I need to make uses the PATCH method which HttpUrlConnection apparently doesn't support.  While I was searching for a workaround, I ran across the [OkHttp client](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) which apparently does support the PATCH method.  On the website for OkHttp it says:

"You can try out OkHttp without rewriting your network code. The okhttp-urlconnection module implements the familiar java.net.HttpURLConnection API.."

I downloaded the jar file (as well as the Okio dependency) and added them to my project.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any information on their website (I looked through the wiki and javadocs) about how I can "try out OkHttp without rewriting" all my existing HttpUrlConnection code.  Am I just misunderstanding what they mean by that statement or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It states without rewriting not without any modification....  The only modification you need to do is obtaining httpurlconnectiin itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [OkUrlFactory](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp-urlconnection/com/squareup/okhttp/OkUrlFactory.html), which comes in the `okhttp-urlconnection` module.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thanks very much!

Comment: link is down. A little bit more information could be appreciate

Comment: Try http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp-urlconnection/com/squareup/okhttp/OkUrlFactory.html

Comment: Don't use OkUrlFactory - It's being deprecated

Comment: Any solution to this, if OkUrlFactory was removed?

Comment: There’s files you can paste here: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/changelog_3x/#version-3140

Comment: @JesseWilson How do i create a HttpUrlConnection from OkHttpClient with recent version of OkHttp? I need this for https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android library. What you said above is how we still proceed here? https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/pull/621#issuecomment-992326397